# How to call procedure from another Form in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

If i have 2 Forms, and i create procedure in Form1 how to call it from Form 2?

I heard about "Call Back Procedure" and "Procedural Types" but i don't know how to use that.

Can someone write me example of Call Back Procedure using Procedural Types and 2 Forms.

Comment: If the procedure belongs to form1 (in the body of the class Tform1) then put it in the public section and call it from the second form if they are both written in the same unit ( yes they can be in the same unit file) if not then simply write the unit name of the first form then a dot then the name of the form then a dot then the procedure ( unit1.form1.dosomthing). If it does not belong to the body of the form then write the title of the procedure (declaration) in the interface section and call it like this from the second unit ( unit1.dosomthing)

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569398/call-procedure-on-another-form